# MySQL - Multiple choice question - New table to store question category?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a multiple choice question form. I am using Flask on the back-end and MySQL as a database.

There will be more than 1 end-user. I already made a users table but haven't work on it yet
There are multiple questions but I only display one question at once.
Every question have either 3 or 4 possible choices (A, B, C or A, B, C, D)
There is always one correct answer
The user can filter question based on category and get stats by category (% of question answered for this category for example)
Should I create a new table called category which would look like category_id (int, primary_key), category_text (varchar(50))?
[image: MySQL )]

Comment: You definitely should not have what you presently have!

Comment: Answers should be a separate table

Comment: I was actually thinking if I should have 2 separates tables. What should be the primary key of my answer table then? And thanks for suggestion

Comment: answer_id, or (question_id, answer_id). Either would work.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to make the changes right now. I guess the major advantage would be the flexibility?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is better to have the mentioned separate category table for the following reasons:

- Restrict the categories to a predefined limited set.
- You might need only categories regardless of question related data. Reading from questions table to just get category data would hint design issues.
- Avoid having category as a free text in the questions table to avoid mistakes that would need cleanups in the future and complicates grabbing/filtering data.
- Easily extensible if you want to add more information through columns in the category table afterwards.